# Is it possible to make Linux use Unix Domain Socket automatically on local socket

Tags: socket, unix-sockets

My team is developing a micro-service web backend. The developers know nothing about deployment, they just deploy the service with some web framework, such as Springboot. The deployment is controlled by some component, which is just like the K8S, so all of services can be migrated among host machines.

So I was just wondering if it's possible to make use Unix Domain Socket automatically on local socket. For example, if service `a` and service `b` are deployed on the same host today, they would use Unix Domain Socket to communicate with each other. If `b` is replaced by `c` some day, `a` and `c` would use Unix Domain Socket. Otherwise(services are not on a same host), use common socket to communicate.

IMO, what I need is some kind of config of OS like this:

```
config = kernel.read(some_config)
sk = kernel.get_socket(some_socket)
if (config == 1 and sk.destination_ip == 127.0.0.1) {
    sk uses Unix Domain Socket to do the communication
} else {
    sk uses common socket to do the communication
}
```

Is there such a config or such a kind of mechanism on Linux?